# Best practices for truffle app

Tags: dapp-development, truffle, truffle-contract

Hi I'm wondering what are some best practices in terms of directory and file structure when building a truffle application, specifically within the app directory.

I'm building a Dapp with too many functions for one file. I'm wondering if someone could give me some examples about how to nicely separate files for contract functions that go together and bring in truffle contract object and web3 together in a app.js file. Just asking for some nice ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://truffle-box.github.io/. If you are using react this might help you get started.